# CSS textbox- overlay a background over another background

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox that is formatted through a background-image. Now, when some AJAX processing is happening, I want to display a spinning icon in the bottom right of the textbox. I can add the class to the text box when this happens, but it obviously replaces the background.

```
.suburb-loading {
background: url('/images/loading_spinner.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
```

Is their a way to overlay 2 backgrounds? Or what is the best way here to overlay the image over the background?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS multiple backgrounds by just separating them with a comma

```
.suburb-loading {
   background-image: url('1.png'), url('2.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SAVbV/)

Fiddle CSS

```
input {
    background-image: url('http://www.melabev.org/images/spinner.gif?1331633304'), url('http://1-art.eu/images/backgrounds/vellum/vellum-old-vellum-background2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center right, 0 0;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make use of [**CSS3 Multiple Background**](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) feature, but you should know that this [*will not work in all browsers*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), Or you can create another `div` overlaying the original one `like with absolute position` and this will work for old browsers those don't support multiple backgrounds

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go for a new div. through jquery, how would I align the div with the existing box? If I did use multiple backgrounds, because I'm using addClass, how would I add multiple backgrounds? Doing so just replaced the previous one.

Comment: You better use the CSS3 multiple background, and use the div overlayign with jQuery as an alternative solution for browsers lacking support for multiple background